# Can Annotated Tractional attributes be changed in Spring through Java reflection?

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I would like to change the Transaction attributes (especially the TransactionManager ) during runtime via reflection. Is this possible?

eg: @Transactional('ChangeMe')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As fare as I know, Java has no function to modify the annotations at runtime.

But you can use [programmatic transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic), instead of the annotation.

On the other hand you can try to modify springs declarative transaction management, to enable and disable the transactions by some List or Map, but not by reflection.

Additional references:

- [How to add Annotations at Runtime to a java class method using Javassist?](http://ayoubelabbassi.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-add-annotations-at-runtime-to.html) (they modify the class, but this mean creating a new one -- that is how I understand it)

Comment: your only option is to handle this programmatically as changing a Spring annotation to change transactional behaviour would require spring to reload the relevant beans.

Comment: Thanks guys . I guess I cannot modify the annotation . I am thinking of some workaround using AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.